# How to highlight cell if any of 6 cells to the right not blank

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to highlight the value in column `D` if any of the cells in the same rows from columns `E:K` are not blank.  I have tried this formula in custom formatting:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK($E137:K137))
```

This works for that one cell, but when I apply to range (`D137:D152`) it highlights all of the cells in range `D`, even though some of the rows are blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...**highlight** the value in **Column** D **if any of the cells in the same rows** from Column E:K **are not blank**

Please try the following formula for the range `D137:D152`

```
=NOT(COUNTIF(E137:K137,"<>")=0)
```

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!